# Where can I find desert random encounter tables?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, encounter-tables

The players in my Greyhawk campaign are about to enter the Bright Desert, and I'd like to use some desert-specific random encounter tables — does anyone have anything suitable? Edition is irrelevant, since I can always convert. Game system is also pretty irrelevant although I probably want fantasy tables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't get more detailed than this. [Necromancer Games Mother of all encounter tables](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product_info.php?products_id=1618&it=1&filters=0_0_0_0_0).

Answer (score 4):

The AD&D 1st edition [*Monster Manual II*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/43623/monster-manual-ii) contains an extensive appendix of random encounter tables by terrain.

Being the last-published monster book for AD&D 1e, it includes every book-published AD&D monster in its  tables. Also, because of the close ties between AD&D and Greyhawk, these tables should suit the Bright Desert particularly well.

Copies in used condition can be had for about $15 to $20 online.

Answer (score 3):

I like this one, that I use on occasion: [‎Jreyst's desert terrain random encounter table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/community-creations/house-rules/random-encounters/terrain/desert).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Bryant in a comment: http://donjon.bin.sh/4e/encounter is pretty good too.